# Error: pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Match multiple column in different sets and update an another column with the all the unmatched column name separated by ,

Update the result column with the unmatched column name

**Input:**

```
  A  B  C  D  E
0  f  e  b  a  d
1  c  b  a  c  b
2  f  f  a  b  c
3  d  c  c  d  c
4  f  b  b  b  e
5  b  a  f  c  d
```

**Expected Output**

```
   A  B  C  D  E           MATCHES
0  f  e  b  a  d  AD, BC Unmatched
1  c  b  a  c  b      BC Unmatched
2  f  f  a  b  c  AD, BC Unmatched
3  d  c  c  d  c       ALL MATCHED
4  f  b  b  b  e      AD Unmatched
5  b  a  f  c  d  AD, BC Unmatched
```

**The below code gives Error when using it inside function Else its working fine if i am using separately without use of any function.**

```
def test(x):
    try:
       for idx in df.index:
           unmatch_list = []
           if not df.loc[idx, 'A'] == df.loc[idx, 'D']:
              unmatch_list.append('AD')
           if not df.loc[idx, 'B'] == df.loc[idx, 'C']:
              unmatch_list.append('BC')
           # etcetera...
           if len(unmatch_list):
              unmatch_string = ', '.join(unmatch_list) + ' Unmatched'
           else:
              unmatch_string = 'ALL MATCHED'
           df.loc[idx, 'MATCHES'] = unmatch_string
 
     except ValueError:
```

It Gives Error when trying to process:

```
if not df.loc[idx, 'A'] == df.loc[idx, 'D']:
Error: pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Need Suggestions:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is called function?

For me working if add `return df` and pass `DataFrame` to function:

```
def test(x):
    try:
       for idx in df.index:
           unmatch_list = []
           if not df.loc[idx, 'A'] == df.loc[idx, 'D']:
              unmatch_list.append('AD')
           if not df.loc[idx, 'B'] == df.loc[idx, 'C']:
              unmatch_list.append('BC')
           # etcetera...
           if len(unmatch_list):
              unmatch_string = ', '.join(unmatch_list) + ' Unmatched'
           else:
              unmatch_string = 'ALL MATCHED'
           df.loc[idx, 'MATCHES'] = unmatch_string
          
 
    except ValueError:
         print ('error')
    return df

df = test(df)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E           MATCHES
0  f  e  b  a  d  AD, BC Unmatched
1  c  b  a  c  b      BC Unmatched
2  f  f  a  b  c  AD, BC Unmatched
3  d  c  c  d  c       ALL MATCHED
4  f  b  b  b  e      AD Unmatched
5  b  a  f  c  d  AD, BC Unmatched
```

Solution with `apply` is possible, but is necessary change function like:

```
def test(x):
    try:
        unmatch_list = []
        if not x['A'] == x['D']:
           unmatch_list.append('AD')
        if not x['B'] == x['C']:
           unmatch_list.append('BC')
        # etcetera...
        if len(unmatch_list):
           unmatch_string = ', '.join(unmatch_list) + ' Unmatched'
        else:
           unmatch_string = 'ALL MATCHED'
 
    except ValueError:
         print ('error')
    return unmatch_string

df['MATCHES'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E           MATCHES
0  f  e  b  a  d  AD, BC Unmatched
1  c  b  a  c  b      BC Unmatched
2  f  f  a  b  c  AD, BC Unmatched
3  d  c  c  d  c       ALL MATCHED
4  f  b  b  b  e      AD Unmatched
5  b  a  f  c  d  AD, BC Unmatched
```